# resolving a promise created by then?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 return Promise.resolve(member + 2).then((result) => {return result + 2});
```

Original promise was resolved, the `then` created a new promise? So now this second promise has a value of `result + 2` but is still pending? How do I resolve it?

Comment: The second `then`? I only see one `then`...

Comment: @LarsH, yes I was referring to that one.

Comment: the Promise returned by then **is** resolved ... unless the value returned by then is a Promise, then the Promise returned by .then "adopts" the returned Promise

Comment: I think the name `Promise.resolve` confuses a lot of people; it doesn't force synchronous evaluation or anything like that; it's just a method for creating a "resolved" (successful) promise from a value.

Comment: `but is still pending` - it's pending because `.then` is asynchronous

Comment: @Jacob - however, any "use" of the resolved promise (using .then) **is** asynchronous

Comment: Yes, `.then()` is _always_ asynchronous.

Comment: Stop asking the same question over and over again. You're extremely confused. Promises are not something **you** resolve, by calling `then` or returning something from the handler, or anything else. They **are** resolved, either by the person/library constructing them, or by virtue of the promise on which the `then` is called being resolved. How could **you** possibly resolve something which might not exist yet? You are confusing "resolve" with "getting the value of". The way you get the value of a promise is by hanging a then off it, and consulting the parameter passed to the handler.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then , it clearly says `When a value is simply returned from within a then lambda, it will effectively return Promise.resolve(<value returned by whichever handler was called>).` So return inside of a then is the same as Promise.resolve(). If someone said that in the first place I would never have been confused. @torazaburo

Comment: You're confused about what `Promise.resolve` does. It does not resolve a promise. It **creates** an already-resolved promise. Resolving does not mean to somehow magically create a synchronous value from a promise. That is impossible--you cannot turn an asynchronous value into a synchronous one. Resolve means to **put** a promise into the resolved state, with an associated value, and as I said, it is not something that is done by the `then` handler, or by returning something from within it.

Comment: Then I see what you mean, then we use another handler, and do some operation with the resolved value right (eg console log)? @torazaburo

Answer (score 1):

Promises are **always** evaluated asynchronously, meaning it's impossible to "resolve" the promise back into a synchronous environment. The only way to access the value of a `Promise` is inside a `then` or `catch` callback.

```js
Promise.resolve(10)
       .then(result => result + 2)
       .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x =Promise.resolve(10 + 2).then((result) => {return result+2});
     x.then((value)=>console.log(value));

// 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call then() to get new result:

```
let promise = Promise.resolve(17).then(res => res + 2000);

promise.then(newRes => {
  console.log("newRes",newRes) // 2017
})
```

GoodLuck!